# how to apply a fix in openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I need to apply this fix: https://review.openstack.org/#/c/22305/

I copy pasted the following line into the terminal.

```
  root@grid1:/home/username/openstackgeek# git fetch https://review.openstack.org/openstack/glance refs/changes/05/22305/1 && git checkout
```

answer is :

```
FETCH_HEAD
    warning: no common commits
    remote: Counting objects: 15564, done
    remote: Finding sources: 100% (15564/15564)
    remote: Total 15564 (delta 9487), reused 13155 (delta 9487)
    Receiving objects: 100% (15564/15564), 6.10 MiB | 126 KiB/s, done.
    Resolving deltas: 100% (9487/9487), done.
    From https://review.openstack.org/openstack/glance
     * branch            refs/changes/05/22305/1 -> FETCH_HEAD
    Note: checking out 'FETCH_HEAD'.

    You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
    changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
    state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

    If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
    do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

      git checkout -b new_branch_name

    HEAD is now at 12d28c3... Swallow UserWarning from glance-cache-manage
```

Is there any step else to complete this fix or that's all ?. I am doing this fix because I get the error below and i still get it:

```
root@grid1:/home/username/openstackgeek# glance-cache-manage  list-cached
Cache management middleware not enabled on host 0.0.0.0
```

I hope you guys help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying from source code on a tagged release of openstack and not a packaged release.

try something like this:

```
mkvirtualenv glance
pip install -r tools/pip-requires
python setup.py build
easy_install dist/glance-xxxxxxx.egg
```